# (Java, Android) Botão - Definir limite de Click's

Tags: java, android

Boas, alguém me pode dizer como é que se define um limite para o número de click's num botão, e ao atingir esse limite, impedir que o botão seja clicado de novo?

Aqui está:

```
 public void N1(View v) {
    EditText editTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextView);
    TextView tvN1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNumero1);
    editTextView.append(tvN1.getText().toString());}
```

Este botão funciona como uma tecla de um teclado, ao ser clicado mostra o carater no editText. Eu queria que, primeiro, fosse obrigatório carregar no botão antes de passar a fase seguinte, mas impedir que o botão fosse clicado mais do que uma vez...

Obrigado se me puderem ajudar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, basta utilizar a propriedade setEnabled(false);

```
final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        btn.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, mas já agora, sabes como posso contar as vezes que se clica num botão?

Comment: @EduardoBrito utilizando uma variável que incrementa dentro do código de `click` e não esquecendo do guardar e restaurar estado da `Activity`

Answer (score 2):

isso aqui pode te ajudar

```
int quantidade_clicks = 0;
int vezes_click = 5;

public void N1(View v) {
    if(this.quantidade_clicks<=this.vezes_click){
        EditText editTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextView);
        TextView tvN1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNumero1);
        editTextView.append(tvN1.getText().toString());
        this.quantidade_clicks++;
        return;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this,"você não pode clicar mais de "+String.valueOf(this.vezes_click)+ "vezes!",10).show();
}
```

Comment: Eu tiraria os `findViewById()` de dentro do método.

Comment: @ramaral ele deve ta afetando uma outra view do mesmo layout do botão  ao clica-lo